# PowerShell string variable within array to array variable

Tags: powershell

I have a string variable like this:

```
$a = "{VAR1: 'value1', VAR2: 'value2', VAR3: 'value3'}"
```

I have found $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($variable) to execute string commands

Is there a way in PowerShell to get that string directly as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6) for that:

```
$a = "{VAR1: 'value1', VAR2: 'value2', VAR3: 'value3'}"
$b = ConvertFrom-Json $a
```

Then you can access like this:

```
$b.VAR2
```

Or if you want an array of the values:

```
$MyArray = (ConvertFrom-Json $a).PSObject.Properties | select -ExpandProperty value
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for something simple like that